Help in identifying this dot-sized insect crawling on my bed
While laying in bed scrolling on my phone I found this crawling in it. It is extremely small, no bigger then the  period in this text, could barely see it with the naked eye, I had to zoom in like 10-14x with the phone and the image is not the best.


I live in Louisiana and have 2 pets, a cat and a dog. I am around livestock at times and live in a rural area and also hunt in the wild. Please help me identify this insect.

Please update if you end up finding more than 1

Good post.
It's a tick, possibly first instar, probably a nymph and definitely unengorged, for example Ixodes scapularis (post-edit there are numerous other candidates). This is the obvious answer, particularly with a dog, possibly cats in a rural area. They are definitely diurnal and will travel via pets. Ticks are present in Louisiana, but not endemic to my understanding - so its rarity would fit.
An ixodid tick would fit the bill. In the top picture it's very difficult to see its legs - I think that's the camera angle - unengorged ixodid ticks have long legs, longer than their body. Again post-edit, there are numerous alternative tick species in the US.
If you zoom in on the second picture - that's a tick, it has 8 legs (to my counting) and they are distinct and larger than its body .... The back legs are very characteristic but I can't get a good photo to demonstrate the identification.
The difficulty I'm having is deciding what instar it is. I don't think it's a larva, because its legs are too small in comparison to its body. I definitely recognise the back legs - but I can't place it. I'm wondering whether it's a nymph or adult male, at a guess I'd go for nymph. An adult male BTW will not feed (but I think they can attach - not sure), anyway they're really hanging around for a female. Basically it would fit this being a male better, but they are a bit bigger than nymphs.
Face to face the difference between larvae, nymph and adult male is obvious because of their size differences. Here it's difficult to see that. BTW it appears to have a marking on the back of its "shell" zoomed in on the second photo - that will be diagnostic to a tick expert; there will be Lyme's experts on the site and they'll be able to give a species identification.

At first (top photo) I thought it was first instar Cimex lectularius unengorged (bedbugs) - that's the photo below far left.
The evidence that its not Cimex

rural area, bedbugs are in cities
its broad daylight and Cimex are strictly nocturnal.
they only have 6 legs. The second photo zoomed shows 8 (to my sight anyway (* post edit note, I'm not really sure it has 8 legs on review, it might have 6*).


Image above is a Cimex first instar engorging (feeding on blood) to demonstrate the change in morphology as they feed. The image and associated info are from here.

I've been asked to respond to a "peer-review" process by @theforestecologist.
Male ticks and feeding
First up the comments stated that male ticks feed and I clearly stated they do not feed. The citation given in the comments was from CDC's website, I think it was here. An example of a statement supporting this idea is (I don't think it was the specific sentence cited),

After the eggs hatch, the ticks must have a blood meal at every stage to survive.

I studied Ixodes ricinus for my PhD, i.e. European ticks and the expert opinion was that the male ixodid tick didn't feed. This has been comprehensively addressed by Troughton and Levin (2007) "Life Cycles of Seven Ixodid Tick Species (Acari: Ixodidae) Under Standardized Laboratory Conditions" in J. Med. Entomol., the journal is an authority in arthropods. The authors' did not observe any engorging behaviour for Ixodes scapularis males,

Males were rarely seen attached to the rabbit, but they were observed copulating with females and crawling around the feeding bag between attached females. The majority of males died while on the rabbit by the seventh day.

"Attached" is the only way the male tick can feed, it's not clear whether they are feeding however and they are not engorging. Basically, the male tick can spend 1 to 2.5 hours copulating, whilst the female will feed for several days. Thus "briefly" and "rarely" will be "minutes" and for a tick even at larvae stage this is not sufficient to engorge and moult to the next stage of development. After the male tick has mated that its final stage of its lifecycle. The CDC statement applies to larvae, nymphs and female ticks.

Distribution of Ixodes scapularis
It's important to note Louisiana has been key to the ecology of Ixodes scapularis from when the first surveys were performed. This is a comprehensive study from Eisen and Eisen (2023), Ticks and Tick-borne Diseases

The time series clearly shows I. scapularis was present in Louisiana from 1912 onwards. Thus the OP is in the vicinity of what is commonly called the "deer" or "black-legged" tick.
The reason why I brought this up early is the OP states they go hunting, presumably with their dog, and presumably for deer, so the OP will be within ecoregions of  where the deer ticks distribution is described above.

Evidence for ticks
Its important to note there are numerous and morphologically diverse tick species in the USA, not just the "black-legged" or "deer" tick, but also the brown dog tick, American dog tick, winter tick, the lone star tick and so on... The photo could be any of those. The presence of both "hard" ticks, aka ixodid ticks, and "soft" ticks in the US, together with their complex instar lifecycle mean there is a huge morphological diversity of ticks in the US. It's not like Europe. In Europe there's only one predominant species of ixodid tick.  In addition, partial engorgement of a soft tick, such as a lone star tick could represent the top photo, but in my opinion not the second photo (zoomed in).
Could it be a tick larvae?
Yes,

if you believe the second picture zoomed in has 6 legs not 8 legs -- then its a larvae, e.g. CDC describes tick larvae as having 6 legs, also Dubie et al (2017) (below).
ixodid tick larvae can be just less than 1mm (below), depending how they are measured
there is a strong fit with the OP's hunting and deer tick ecology
there is no hair visible on any part of either photo by the OP and that is a critical anatomical feature of all mites along with 8 legs.

In addition, it could by any number of species not necessarily the deer tick (see below for winter tick and American dog tick [which are closely related]). On review does the tick have 8 legs or 6 legs?  It might only have 6 legs - in that case it's a clear identification of a tick larvae.

The above image shows from left to right, the larvae, nymph, male instar and female instar of I. scapularis (deer or black-legged tick). The point is that larvae are very small, but equally unfed nymphs are also small.
Could it be a nympth?
Quite possibly:

Nymphs have 8 legs (is there 8 legs in the zoomed second photo? There could just be 6 legs)
Nymphs can also be very small (picture of I. ricinus below)
The ecology and OP's hunting as well as the lack of hair fit in the photos fit with this being a tick.


Note the image of I. ricinus above is taken from van Duijvendijk et al 2016 Parasite and Vectors The ticks are visibly different from any American tick, but the size distribution are very similar. What I want to show is that nymphs (top right of the 4 ticks) are also small. The larvae is the bottom right of the 4

What species of tick is it?
The ecology fits the deer tick, but it could be any number of ticks. For example, an alternative is the brown dog tick could easily be a candidate:

An image of the brown dog tick
Second alternative example is Dermacentor albipictus (winter tick) is intriguing, whose habitat will include Louisiana, if you zoom into the second photo the OP took there is a "lighter patch" just below half down on the ticks shell. That must be diagnostic because thats rare in ticks (lone star females have a "white spot" but it's not the same location). That has distinct resonance to the image of a winter tick from Dubie et al (2017) Identification of Immature Stages of Common Ixodid Ticks Found in Pastures in Oklahoma 2017 Southwestern Entomologist 42(1):1-14. It important to note the picture is taken using strong light and this will shift the leg colouration. The image of interest is the top left and the publication makes it clear that there is variation in size of the "white spot" on the tick larvae (some tick larvae don't have it). A coloration spot is really unusual for a juvenile tick.

Third alternative examples is the American dog tick is the same genus Dermacentor variabilis and both are ixodid ticks.
Finally, it may be possible it's a soft tick such as the lone star tick (the image here is an adult female).
Note The brown dog tick and American dog tick are different genera of "hard" tick aka ixodid tick. Similar names but genetically quite different. The deer tick is also an ixodid tick.
Anyway you get the idea, there are lots of ticks in the USA and their diversity is not always well documented, i.e. Dubie et al is 2017 for a morphological identification paper (that would never happen in Europe :-) ).

Could the photos be mites?
In summary No. The counter hypothesis is that this a mite rather than a tick. Personally, I can't see this, but to demonstrate this: a comprehensive overview on the differences between ticks and mites is give at https//study.com entitled "Video: How Do Ticks & Mites Differ?". The video is a great resource and makes it clear mites can look like ticks but there are key differences:

mites are much smaller than ticks, the overwhelming majority being <1mm
for example, mites that live on the human face (which we all have) are not observable by eye
mites have hair and ticks have no hair (see below)
ALL mites have 8 legs (I'm not sure whether the OPs photo has 8 legs).

There are no visible hairs in any photo by the OP and if the photo by the OP has 6 legs - it sure ain't a mite.
The second issue is what mite species could it be? Common mites that that can be confused for ticks would be beetle mites, chiggers mites and chicken mites but none of these fit (below). There might also be also be associated signatures, for example chicken mite infestation.
Beetle mites
Beetle mites can be confused for an engorged tick larvae, but like all mites they have visible hair (below):

Chiggers mites
The issue here is like many mites they are very small <0.3mm and the question is whether cellphone could achieve that resolution? The other issue is they bite human legs causing a red spot, which I think (I could be wrong) itches. Ticks bites don't result in inflammation, chiggers bites do (maybe the OP has this?). Tick bite "inflammation" BTW is the onset of Lyme's infection.
Chicken mites
If the OP has chickens then the onset of a chicken mite infestation is possible. Chicken mites are large up to 1.5 mm which is huge for a mite. However, chicken mites don't look like the photos the OP has shown, particularly their legs are a different colour, in addition they are known as red chicken mites and these arthropods can be red,

Summary

It's a tick larvae if the second photo comprises 6 legs and not 8. The ecology fits very strongly with deer ticks and dogs do pick up ticks: deer ticks, brown dog ticks, American dog ticks, winter ticks, lone star ticks - huge morphological diversity in the US.
It's a nymph if the second photo comprises 8 legs. Again the ecology fits strongly, but again the morphological diversity of US ticks is large.
It's a mite if the resolution of a cellphone can identify a mite <0.3mm for many mites, or large mites <1mm, but fail to identify the hair of the arthropod. There would need to be a candidate species which better fits any species that I am aware of, nothing I know fits at all.

Final note  I can't see any other outcome except that its a tick

Definitely not a bed bug. Though, I also don't think this is a tick.  Looks like some other mite. Your answer includes appreciated depth when comparing to bed bugs, but you really lack any strong/cited evidence to support that this is a tick vs any other mite species (let alone any cited evidence for the specific species you suggest -- with presence of dog not being very convincing by itself). Look at leg orientation and apparent lack of scutum. OP's pic is small, so this isn't easy, but your post needs more cited evidence to support your answer

@theforestecologist thats a tick - I studied Ixodes ricinus for my PhD (European ixodid tick), but its good we agree its not an insect. Your information on the CDC is inaccurate and potentially misleading; it depends what you mean by "male ticks". The issue is that the male instar is not believed to feed, however all larvae, nymphs feed - they take a single blood-meal to moult to the next stage. Thats how it is written it; I would urge not to press the point, which at best is highly debatable. I am very sorry but I cannot agree with your posts; an expert in Lyme's disease is required.

I don't think it's impossible for the OP's image to be a larval tick, but I still personally doubt it. However, what's important is that you've not provided enough explicit evidence to support your answer. In other words, I don't want you to read any of this as "me vs you" -- it's a bad picture so it's not 100% clear either way. Instead, please read all of this as a form of peer review encouraging you to provide more explicit detail for why you're correct and for the need to provide reputable sources to back up your claims and address commentator concerns. Build the strongest argument you can.

Again I will put together a literature review as promised. Please note, it is weekend at the time of writing and tomorrow is Christmas Eve.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Thanks for taking the time to edit. The inclusion of additional links/citations is good. However, your edits overall are meandering and unclear. Many issues exist throughout. Most importantly, you did not strongly address the issue at hand: why tick vs any other mite. The lone section that addresses this uses a lousy source (study.com, in fact not even a strongly written nor accurate study.com post written by a man with MA in Physics Education who teaches high school chem & physics). Odd choice by a tick expert. Though longer, the post is not improved and has many issues. Please [edit].

@theforestecologist I will respond with formal citations. I will contact study.com independently to ask them to comment on the validity of their study material and cite your criticism in the context of their IP.
